# How to change the default appbar buttons for the whole app

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I need to change implement custom Icons for default button and drawer button for all pages in my project.

I know we have the option of using `leading` property, however, this only affects that certain page.

How can we change the default **back button** and **open drawer button** of `AppBar` in Flutter for the whole app?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not a property called defaultBackButton or defaultDrawerButton.

So, in order to change these defaults in the whole app, we can create a CustomAppBar which and set Icons as we wish.

Please [click here to see Demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=b241142d081306b9fb2c2c1bf53da79c) and test it yourself.

For a bit longer description, checkout my [Medium story](https://medium.com/@suatozkaya/change-the-default-appbar-buttons-for-the-whole-app-f9b5ff3773f7).

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final Widget? leading;
  final Widget? title;
  final bool? centerTitle;
  final bool automaticallyImplyLeading;

  const CustomAppBar({
    Key? key,
    this.leading,
    this.title,
    this.centerTitle,
    this.automaticallyImplyLeading = true,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// This part is copied from AppBar class
    final ScaffoldState? scaffold = Scaffold.maybeOf(context);
    final bool hasDrawer = scaffold?.hasDrawer ?? false;
    final ModalRoute<dynamic>? parentRoute = ModalRoute.of(context);
    final bool canPop = parentRoute?.canPop ?? false;

    Widget? leadingIcon = leading;

    if (leadingIcon == null && automaticallyImplyLeading) {
      if (hasDrawer) {
        leadingIcon = IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.mood_sharp, color: Colors.yellowAccent),
          onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
        );
      } else {
        if (canPop) {
          leadingIcon = IconButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.sentiment_dissatisfied_sharp,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }

    return AppBar(
      leading: leadingIcon,
      title: title,
      centerTitle: centerTitle,
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Comment: I concur, flutter lacks such default and that is good. not everything needs a default. Another option is even to create a custom scaffold that will have this custom appbar and keeping using your custom scaffold instead of Material's Scaffold